# Validate Admob reward video using PHP

Tags: android, admob

I added video ads for an android game, but it must be verified by PHP before the points can be added but I didn't find anyway to check it.

Answer (score 3):

Admob now supports server-side verification for reward ads.
Here is the [reference](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9603226?hl=en), and for [client-side](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/ssv#custom_data). Here is example PHP code that I edited from [an article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/88896692781/).:

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["signature"])) {

        //Get current admob public keys
        $verifier_keys = file_get_contents('https://www.gstatic.com/admob/reward/verifier-keys.json');
        
        if(!$verifier_keys_arr = json_decode($verifier_keys, true)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Public Keys");
        } elseif(!is_array($verifier_keys_arr)) {
            throw new Exception("Empty Public Keys");
        }

        $public_key_pem = $verifier_keys_arr['keys'][0]['pem'];

        //Admob sdk will send the query string upon watching ad, just grab them:
        $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

        $signature = trim($_GET['signature']);
        // The important thing is the replacement and padding of the signature result string here
        $signature = str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $signature);
        $signature .= '===';

        // The data element string for signing
        $message = substr($query_string, 0, strpos($query_string, 'signature')-1);

        if(openssl_verify($message, $signature, $public_key_pem, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)){
            //verified
            $output = "verified";

            //Get All keys from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/ssv#ssv_callback_parameters
            $reward_item = $_GET['reward_item'];
            $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
            $custom_data = $_GET['custom_data'];

            //Now do your things after validating the ad response
            //for example
            if($custom_data==="GIVE_COINS") {
                //give coins
            } elseif($custom_data==="LEVEL_UP") {
                //level up
            }

        } else {
            //echo openssl_error_string();
            throw new Exception("Unable to verify the query");
        }
    } else {
        // do nothing, somebody just opened the link
        //echo `Error 404, this page not exists`
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Rewarded video returns a specific value based on the configuration provided while creating the Rewarded Video Ad unit. It's by default set to **1**. Means when user watches the rewarded video without cancelling it, You'll get **1** as from the callback. You can call the REST Api endpint(php) in **`onUserEarnedReward`** callback method. Here is the sample implementation from [Official Docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads)

```java
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (rewardedAd.isLoaded()) {
            Activity activityContext = ...;
            RewardedAdCallback adCallback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                    // Ad opened
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                    // Ad closed without completion
                }

                @Override
                public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem reward) {
                    // User earned reward call the rest api
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int errorCode) {
                    // Ad failed to display.
                }
            };
            rewardedAd.show(activityContext, adCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
    }
});
```

The [Official Integration Docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads) has several boilerpellet codes might help you through. Follow the instruction and you'll good to go.

> **Caution:**  The Rest API Endpoint should be protected with authorization, Otherwise, it will be vulnerable to false calls from outside of the application.

Comment: thank you for reply ..
but in this way the user can fake the php call , i am looking for a solution to make it secure

Comment: I already mentioned that in caution. You can secure the rest api endpoint by some authorization mechanism like JWT to prevent false calls.